# RQT_plot - cmd_vel, odometry, displaying complex messege data

Tags: ros-melodic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use rqt_plot for displaying cmd_vel-odometry relation. Whats the easiest way to do so? Is there a function to open all the vectors at once? What are the messeges datafields called, odom/angular.z, odom/twist/angular_z, ....?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349921/rqt_plot---cmd_vel,-odometry,-displaying-complex-messege-data./) by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 574 on 2020-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to consider using PlotJuggler instead. It will make much easier to display and compare data, like this.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-05-04**:
Thanks, that looks like what I was looking for.